# Jquery + Ajax in rails app making submit button become invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk to create new `Collections` on-screen.

It seems to be working, except when I click on the Create collection form link, my form submit button becomes a tiny square, barely visible.

Here's my `new.js.erb` view:

```
$('#new_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

Here's my new.html.erb view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New collection') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create collection') %>

<div class="container">
    <h1>New collection</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <%= render 'form' %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my form partial:

```
<div id="form">
  <%= form_for([@seller, @collection]) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @collection %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', id: 'collection-input' %>
    <br>

    <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here's the index view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Collections') %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Create a new collection</h4>
            <p class="card-text">                     
                <%= link_to 'Create collection', new_seller_collection_path(@seller), { :class=>"btn btn-primary", :id=>"new_link", remote: true } %>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here's a screenshot of what happens (top left card):
[image: screenshot]

Any idea on how to fix it? I'm obviously clueless. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has the id `#new_link`? Is it the create button, and possibly `.hide()` is being called on it? Also - what is `yield(:button_text)` - do you know that is calling anything? It's a bit hard to tell with what you have posted.

Comment: @gwalshington sorry! I forgot to add the `index.html.erb` contents. I edited the question and will clarify here: `#new_link` is the create button (that calls `CollectionsController#New`). So when that button is clicked it's supposed to be hidden and the form displayed in-line. the `yield(:button_text)` corresponds with this line from `new.html.erb` : `<% provide(:button_text, 'Create collection') %>` so it just gives it that text. Thanks for your help!